# find the nearest parent which has class

Tags: jquery, recursion

Assume we have the following markup:

```
<div class="hello">
  <p>
    <a href="#"><span id="start">Start</span></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Is there any way to find the closest element to `$('#start')` which has a class attribute, going up the dom tree?

CLARIFICATION:
I actually need to get a string containing the complete path from $('#start') to $(.hello), which would contain the tag names of all elements until the 
So based on the markup above - it would output: '**span a p .hello**'

You can get the elements tag name with `element.prop('tagName')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the closest element, *including the one you started with*, use `.closest`:

```
$('#start').closest('[class]');
```

If you want to exclude the starting element, use this:

```
$('#start').parents('[class]').first();
```

To get the full matching path, try this:

```
var path = [];
var el = document.getElementById('start');
while (el) {
    if (el.className) {
        path.push('.' + el.className);
        break;
    } else {
        path.push(el.tagName);
    }
    el = el.parentNode;
}
var ancestors = path.join(' ');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/EZWNR/

I used native JS because jQuery doesn't AFAIK provide a simple method to select an element *and* every one of its ancestors.

Answer (score 10):

What about

```
$('#start').closest("[class]");
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted, but I actually need something different (I updated the question) sorry about that

Answer (score 4):

You can get a *string containing parent node names till you encounter one with a class* using jQuery's `parents()`: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxfwv/)**

```
var path = 'span ';
$('#start').parents().each(function() {
    if($(this).is('[class]')) {
        path += '.' + this.className + ' ';
        return false; // break
    }
    else {
        path += this.nodeName + ' ';
    }
});
console.log(path);
```

Yes, you can do:

```
$('#start').closest("[class]");
```

Comment: Thanks for a jQuery soluton!